# Expansion of command for language in otherlanguage environment

Tags: macros, expansion, babel

I wish to keep the language in a command

```
\newcommand{\testlang}{english}
\begin{otherlanguage}{\testlang}
 ...
\end{otherlangauge}
```

However, `\testlang` is not expanded, and i get the error

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language testlang yet.
```

I've seen many tricks related to macro expansions, but I don't understand them well enough to know how to apply them in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expand the argument manually using the following techniques. The easiest thing would be to define your own wrapper environment.

```
% Expand the argument once:
\newenvironment{Otherlanguage}[1]{%
  \expandafter\otherlanguage\expandafter{#1}%
}{\endotherlanguage}


% Alternative: argument is fully expanded
\newenvironment{Otherlanguage}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\otherlanguage{#1}}%
  \temp
}{\endotherlanguage}

% usage    
\begin{Otherlanguage}{\testlang}
 ...
\end{Otherlangauge}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason why `otherlanguage` shouldn't try to expand this by default?

Comment: @Mikael Öhman: It's much saver to not expand it inside `\edef`. If it contains things which can't be expanded but must be executed, like assignments, than it will break inside `\edef`. This is very similar to the fragile vs. robust issue in sectioning commands.