# Expansion of macro in environment argument

Tags: macros, environments, expansion

I'd like to generate an environment that changes a bit according to an argument given for it. The reason is having different locales in the document. I have defined a command, `EmitLanguageStr` that determines the argument to `otherlanguage` according to the argument that was passed. For example, `\EmitLanguageStr[en] -> english`. See these questions for further context: [ [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476999/string-variable-with-multiple-values), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477656/generalising-a-second-order-macro-with-loops) ]. Here's the environment stripped down.

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][en]{%
    \section*{\EmitAbstractStr[#1]}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{\EmitLanguageStr[#1]}
        \@author\par
        \textbf{\EmitTitle[#1]}\par
}{%
    \end{otherlanguage}
}
```

Turns out other people have had the same problem ([Q](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/expansion-of-command-for-language-in-otherlanguage-environment)), but the solution did not quite work for me. The answer suggests that wrapping the environment in one of two ways would allow the argument to be expanded:

```
% Create a macro
\newcommand\testlang{english}

% Expand the argument once:
\newenvironment{Otherlanguage}[1]{%
    \expandafter\otherlanguage\expandafter{#1}%
}{\endotherlanguage}

% Alternative: argument is fully expanded
\newenvironment{Otherlanguage}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\otherlanguage{#1}}%
    \temp
}{\endotherlanguage}

% usage    
\begin{Otherlanguage}{\testlang}
    ...
\end{Otherlangauge}
```

First, without these wrappers, babel gives an error message that the language `EmitLanguageStr[en]` is not defined. That was addressed in the linked question. However, the solutions presented produce another kind of error: `Use of \EmitLanguageStr doesn't match its definition`.

How can the command be properly expanded?

---

Here's a complete example of the situation. This works, but by switching the argument of `Otherlanguage` to the one in the comment the described error is thrown.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\SetDefaultValue[2]{%
    \global\@namedef{#2:#1}{%
        {\scriptsize (Use {\tt\textbackslash #2[#1]} to replace this text.)}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\MakeLocaleVar[2][en,fi]{%
    \foreach \n in {#1}{%
        \expandafter\SetDefaultValue\expandafter{\n}{#2}
    }%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[2][]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{}}{%
            \foreach \n in {#1}{%
                \global\@namedef{#2:\n}{##2}%
            }%
        }{%
            \global\@namedef{#2:##1}{##2}%
        }%
    }%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname Emit#2\endcsname[1][en]{\@nameuse{#2:##1}}%
}

% Variables set in document
\MakeLocaleVar{Title}
\MakeLocaleVar{Year}

%\newenvironment{Otherlanguage}[1]{%
%   \expandafter\otherlanguage\expandafter{#1}%
%}{\endotherlanguage}

\newenvironment{Otherlanguage}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\otherlanguage{#1}}%
    \temp
}{\endotherlanguage}

\MakeLocaleVar{AbstractStr}
\AbstractStr[en]{ABSTRACT}
\AbstractStr[fi]{TIIVISTELMÄ}

\MakeLocaleVar{LanguageStr}
\LanguageStr[en]{english}
\LanguageStr[fi]{finnish}

\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][en]{%
    \section*{\EmitAbstractStr[#1]}
    \begin{Otherlanguage}{english}%\EmitLanguageStr[#1]
        \@author\par
        \textbf{\EmitTitle[#1]}\par
        \EmitYear\par
        \par
    }{%
    \end{Otherlanguage}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish, english]{babel}

\author{Handsome Devil}
\Year{2019}

\Title[en]{Title in English}
\Title[fi]{Otsikko suomeksi}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract environment in English.
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}[fi]
    Abstract environment in Finnish.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full minimal example instead of sniplets. That makes it a lot easier for others to test your code and provide suggestions

Comment: Seems `\EmitLanguageStr` processes an optional argument. LaTeX-macros that process optional arguments usually are not fully expandable. This means `\EmitLanguageStr` won't expand to tokens only that form the name of a language but it also delivers assignment-tokens like `\@ifnextchar`/`\futurelet` which are used for "looking ahead" at the next token for finding out whether that is a left-bracket. Such assignment-tokens won't vanish during expansion. Besides this for debugging a compilable example is needed which lets you reproduce the erroneous/problematic behavior exactly.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Oh, that's good to know. Minimal example added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\MakeLocaleVar{LanguageStr}` causes `\EmitLanguageStr` to be defined as:

```
\newcommand\EmitLanguageStr[1][en]{\@nameuse{LanguageStr:#1}}%
```

`\EmitLanguageStr` processes an optional argument.

If you look at `\EmitLanguageStr` via `\show\EmitLanguageStr`, you'll find:

```
> \EmitLanguageStr=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \EmitLanguageStr \\EmitLanguageStr {en}.
```

Looking at `\@protected@testopt` yields:

```
> \@protected@testopt=macro:
#1->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \@testopt \else \@x@protect #1
\fi .
```

Looking at `\@testopt` yields:

```
> \@testopt=\long macro:
#1#2->\kernel@ifnextchar [{#1}{#1[{#2}]}.
```

Looking at `\kernel@ifnextchar` yields:

```
> \kernel@ifnextchar=\long macro:
#1#2#3->\let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\futurele
t \@let@token \@ifnch .
```

Looking at `\@ifnch` yields:

```
> \@ifnch=macro:
->\ifx \@let@token \@sptoken \let \reserved@c \@xifnch \else \ifx \@let@token \
reserved@d \let \reserved@c \reserved@a \else \let \reserved@c \reserved@b \fi 
\fi \reserved@c .
```

Looking at `\@xifnch` yields:

```
> \@xifnch=macro:
 ->\futurelet \@let@token \@ifnch .
```

As you can see a lot of playing around with non-expandable `\let`- and `\futurelet`-assignments is involved into the checking for the presence of the optional argument via `\kernel@ifnextchar [`.

Therefore `\EmitLanguageStr` does not only deliver those character tokens that form the name of the language. It also yields a lot of unexpandable assignment-tokens like `\let` and `\futurelet` for checking for the presence of the optional argument.
These tokens won't vanish within a pure-expansion-context while obtaining the name of the language for passing it as argument to an environment would be a pure expansion context. 
After expansion these unexpandable assignment-tokens remain in the token-stream because while expansion takes place in (La)TeX's "gullet", 
the carrying out of assignments takes place in (La)TeX's "stomach".

So in short:

As long as `\EmitLanguageStr` processes an optional argument whereby the techniques for detecting the presence of an optional argument themselves involve non-expandable assignment-tokens  which don't vanish during expansion, you can't use `\EmitLanguageStr` in pure-expansion-contexts for obtaining only those tokens that form the name of the language.

But you can, e.g.,  create a variant of `\EmitLanguageStr` with an additional argument holding tokens to which the emitted string is to be passed as argument. I call that macro `\PassLanguageStrTo`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\SetDefaultValue[2]{%
    \global\@namedef{#2:#1}{%
        {\scriptsize (Use {\tt\textbackslash #2[#1]} to replace this text.)}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%

\newcommand\MakeLocaleVar[2][en,fi]{%
    \foreach \n in {#1}{%
        \expandafter\SetDefaultValue\expandafter{\n}{#2}%%%%
    }%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[2][]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{}}{%
            \foreach \n in {#1}{%
                \global\@namedef{#2:\n}{##2}%
            }%
        }{%
            \global\@namedef{#2:##1}{##2}%
        }%
    }%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname Emit#2\endcsname[1][en]{\@nameuse{#2:##1}}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname Pass#2To\endcsname[2][en]{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname#2:##1\endcsname}{##2}%
    }%
}

% Variables set in document
\MakeLocaleVar{Title}
\MakeLocaleVar{Year}


\MakeLocaleVar{AbstractStr}
\AbstractStr[en]{ABSTRACT}
\AbstractStr[fi]{TIIVISTELMÄ}

\MakeLocaleVar{LanguageStr}
\LanguageStr[en]{english}
\LanguageStr[fi]{finnish}

\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][en]{%
    \section*{\EmitAbstractStr[{#1}]}%%%%
    \PassLanguageStrTo[{#1}]{\begin{otherlanguage}}%
        \@author\par
        \textbf{\EmitTitle[{#1}]}\par
        \EmitYear\par
        \par
    }{%
    \end{otherlanguage}%%%%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish, english]{babel}

\author{Handsome Devil}
\Year{2019}

\Title[en]{Title in English}
\Title[fi]{Otsikko suomeksi}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract environment in English.
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}[fi]
    Abstract environment in Finnish.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```